# Adding a property that is hidden unless it has a value

Tags: powershell, class, object, properties

I'm adding a class related to software packages. Here is a barebones version for the purposes of this question:

```
class Package {
    $Name; $Latest; $Prerelease
    [string]ToString(){ return $this.Name }
}
$test = [Package]::new()
$test.Name = 'Example'
$test.Latest = '0.1'
```

When I perform the command `$test` or `$test | Format-Table`, I want the $Prerelease property to be hidden *unless* it's been given a value.

And, while this next part isn't a requirement, I also want it to be exposed when something like `Format-Table -Force` is used.

I swear I've witnessed other objects in PowerShell behave similarly, but I haven't been able to recall what they were. If this isn't doable for an object made with pure PowerShell, I wouldn't mind something using C# via `Add-Type`.

***P.S.*** In regards to suggesting an alternative, bear in mind I want quoting the object to output the $Name property as it does in the class I posted above, e.g. `"$test"`

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use a specific type/custom class? Using PSCustomObject would make this much easier to solve (simply don't add the `Prerelease` property unless you have a value for it)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have considered that, but I want the class to have a ToString() method that outputs $Name, so that when you input `"$test"` you just get the $Name property. Is that doable with a PSCustomObject? Additionally, I'm wanting this to pipe into another command that would require the class for its InputObject parameter. I could rename the $Name property to something fancy and use ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName instead, but this isn't ideal.

Comment: Also, I went ahead and added the ToString() bit into my question, to better qualify my needs if there's a good alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is easier achieved by simply using a `[PSCustomObject]` expression after conditionally adding properties to the target hashtable/dictionary.

You can then add an override for the `ToString()` method to the resulting object:

```
function New-VopelPackage {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$Name,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$Latest,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [switch]$Prerelease
  )

  # Collect the mandatory properties
  $newPackageProperties = [ordered]@{
    Name = $Name
    Latest = $Latest
  }

  # Conditionally add the optional one
  if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Prerelease')) {
    $newPackageProperties['Prerelease'] = $Prerelease.IsPresent
  }

  # Create the object
  $package = [PSCustomObject]$newPackageProperties 

  # ... and override ToString()
  $toStringMemberParams = @{
    Name       = 'ToString'
    MemberType = 'ScriptMethod'
    Value      = { return $this.Name }
    Force      = $true
    PassThru   = $true
  }

  return $package |Add-Member @toStringMemberParams
}
```

Now you can create package objects with the behavior described:

```
PS ~> $package = New-VopelPackage Example 0.1
PS ~> $package

Name    Latest
----    ------
Example 0.1

PS ~> "$package"
Example
PS ~> $prereleasePackage = New-VopelPackage Example 0.1 -Prerelease
PS ~> $prereleasePackage

Name    Latest Prerelease
----    ------ ----------
Example 0.1          True

PS ~> "$prereleasePackage"
Example
```

Comment: Thank you. The only thing it's missing is some way for another command to identify that the object it's working with is ***unmistakably*** a 'VopelPackage'. Is there a way to add a hidden property to this that it can check for, or something similar?

Comment: I just discovered [PSTypeName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3#pstypename-for-custom-object-types), which should fulfill my needs. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So, I've been using this solution and I'm not completely satisfied. PSTypeName tends to fall off when doing things like piping into Select-Object, which screws up validation. I think there is actually a way to do what I'd like, but it requires C# code and more know-how than I have. I think the key is extending the "INotifyPropertyChanged" class, which I first read about [here](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2015/08/29/an-explanation-of-the-net-add_eventname-remove_eventname-methods/). I added `Console.WriteLine("test");` to OnPropertyChanged to make sure it fires in PowerShell, and it does.

Comment: (Cont.) So my idea with using this is by having class properties with `[HiddenAttribute]` from System.Automation and then, whenever one of the attributes is modified for the first time, using [AddMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.utility.activities.addmember) that to add a new ScriptProperty that functions as a getter for it, and the name would be the attribute name plus a space at the end (since PowerShell allows that). If you could lend your expertise, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure I have enough context here, maybe you'll want to [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)? Please be specific about what it is you're trying to achieve